# Remove everything on the page except anchor tags

Tags: php, file, email

I am trying to create a php program that will allow the user to mass email users, given a certain page. I am loading in a page via php, using the file_get_contents() function.
The site has a list of names (I just need to tag on @gmail.com). There is a lot of unnecessary content and I'd like to only see the anchor tags. If you can also help with the adding on the email domain

Answer (score 1):

you can use the PHP function `strip_tags($text, '<a>);`

That will remove all HTML and PHP tags, except for  tags.

For example:

```
$text = '<b>This is a header</b><br /><span class="text">This is some text</span><a href="#">This is a link</a>';

echo strip_tags($text, '<a>');

// Outputs:
    This is a headerThis is some text<a href="#">This is a link</a>
```